# How to Package and Deploy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, software-packaging

I looked at the SO [Packaging JavaScript & CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283183/packaging-javascript-css)

Now while this does offer 6 applications which can be used. It does not mention [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [Yoeman](http://yeoman.io/) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/)

Or, it addresses after packaging HOW do we deploy JavaScript

There is also [Juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer/)

and [maven Tools for JavaScript](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/)

Here are the takeaways as far as requirements are concerned.

1. For best performance, CSS and JavaScript should be served up using as few requests and bytes as possible
2. Minify JavaScript and CSS.
3. Minimize number of HTTP Requests by combining several files (css, js) into one.
4. Package Management Like what [jamjs](http://jamjs.org/) Provides
5. Dependency Management
6. Removal and Replacement of Packages
7. Building Custom Packages
8. Version Control
9. Publishing
10. Deployment

Can all of above be done with npm ? or just Grunt ? or a combination of the two ?